# Suppressing full pattern match in regex (preg_match())

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The returned matches array contains as the first element the entire string matched, followed by the captured groups.

I can't locate an option on php.net to just return the captured groups?

Is there one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is standard for `0` to contain the entire matched string.

If it were of a concern, you could always `unset($matches[0])` (which won't affect the keys) or `array_slice($matches, 1)`.

Comment: That saved me searching the other half of the regex manual. Thanks.