# Not capturing percent sign in my PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, percentage

Still learning regular expression! My percentage regular expression (not respecting the 100 limit):

```
^(?<int>[1-9][0-9]*|[0])(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?\%?$
```

This *should* allow:

- `[1-9]`  start with a number different from 0. Percentage like "004.34" is not allowed.
- `[0-9]*` ...followed by any digit in between 0 and 9
- `|[0]` or start with a single 0

... capturing this group as "int" group. Then:

- `(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?` an optional group, where a point is allowed only when is followed by at least one digit between 0 and 9. I don't want people to input i.e. "33."

Assuming I'm right, testing with:

```php
preg_match('/^(?<int>[1-9][0-9]*|[0])(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?\%?$/i', '0.32%', $result);
```

Gives me this result, which is actually correct, but:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.32%
    [int] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [dec] => .32
    [2] => .32
)
```

how can avoid capturing the percentage "%" sign (in `$result[0]`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple really. Just change your regex to this:

```
/^(?<int>[1-9][0-9]*|[0])(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?/
```

(Remove `\%?$` from matching).

If you want to make sure that the % sign is there, but don't want to capture it (it seems like it wouldn't matter in this case but maybe) you can add a lookahead assertion. `(?=...)` Assertions make sure that pattern exists, but it doesn't change what is matched.

```
/^(?<int>[1-9][0-9]*|[0])(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?(?=%?$)/
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this will allow any character after the last decimal digit, am I right?

Comment: @Gremo - Right. If you see my edit, it makes sure that it is only a %. I assumed that you had control over the format of the digit since you were plugging it straight in, and not using a variable. In any case, the bottom regex will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Time to learn lookahead stuff :) Btw, why you are using insensitive switch /i with digits?

Comment: @Gremo - Haha I dunno. I just copied and pasted your regex but you're right. You don't need it. :) It's gone now. :)

Comment: (damn Opera not allowing @ mention) Aust, it works in Ruby tester: http://www.rubular.com/r/JgDPnyKeUc but not in a PHP one like this: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/. Aren't they both PCRE?

Comment: @Gremo - It works fine for me there. [Try testing it here.](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) `preg_match('/^(?<int>[1-9][0-9]*|[0])(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?(?=%?$)/', '0.32%', $result);
print_r($result);`

Answer (score 1):

The first element of the `$result` array will always contain the full pattern match (you cannot tell PHP to not do so, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949436/suppressing-full-pattern-match-in-regex-preg-match)), so we have to solve the problem in the regex itself. In your regex you are specifying the `%` will be **within** the **full pattern match** as you explicitly tell it could appear just before (and so, inside) of the end of the pattern string (`$` sign), you do it here `\%?$` .

The solution is to specify the `%` in a lookahead (so it doesn't get into the pattern string) and as your `%` is optional, we tell in the lookahead to look for a `%` or for the end of string, thus the `%` will never enter the full pattern match.

So I added `(?=\%|$)` which tells regex to look ahead for a `%` sign or for the end of the string.

So, the following regex:

```
preg_match('/^(?<int>[1-9][0-9]*|[0])(?<dec>\.[0-9]+)?(?=\%|$)/i', '0.32%', $result);
```

for both '0.32%' and for '0.32' will output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0.32"
  ["int"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["dec"]=>
  string(3) ".32"
  [2]=>
  string(3) ".32"
}
```

**UPDATE:** I updated my full answer, after doing some tests, so read it above